# Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android-studio, ionic2, jvm, cordova-plugins, java-home

I cannot build the app after i installed cordova googleMaps. Getting the following error "Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.".

If i uninstall google maps then i would be able to build without any problem .

Complete error:
1 error
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.676 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  D:\Lenus Phase-2\lenus\platforms\android\src\plugin\google\maps\PluginUtil.java:
  135: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
  Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                                ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeP
  arcelable not found
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).